# Jenkins Pipeline - Git Plugin 3.1.0 - rawRefSpecs not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, git-refspec

I am using Jenkins with the Pipeline Plugin and the Git plugin version 3.1.0.
According to this ticket: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40908, this feature is part of the 3.1.0 version.

I am nevertheless unsuccessful with setting the rawRefSpecs variable.

Here is my pipe configuration:

```
git url: 'ssh://foo/bar.git',
    rawRefSpecs: '+refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*',
    branch: 'bar',
    ...
```

and here is output when I run the plan:

```
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url ssh://foo/bar.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://foo/bar.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress ssh://foo/bar.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/bar^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/bar^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse origin/bar^{commit} # timeout=10
```

We can see that the fetch keeps the default parameter values for the refspecs.

It looks like the GitStep forces the branchspec to be "*/"+branch and ignore any other parameter than branch, credentialsId and url.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/f6ace83fe36740a1ab35612d3b4c5b400647f6ea/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/git/GitStep.java

How could I pass refspec to the command then?

Answer (score 4):

The Git plugin has supported specifying your own refspec for years.  You can find the correct Pipeline syntax via the [Snippet Generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator), under Checkout: General SCM > Git > Repositories > Advanced > Refspec.  This will give you the `checkout` syntax you need.

The `git` step itself does not currently support custom refspecs, and the bug you refer to applies to `GitSCMSource` which, as mentioned in the description, is used for Multibranch Pipelines.

If you're using a Multibranch Pipeline, the new refspec option you're talking about can be found under Branch Sources > Git > Advanced > RefSpecs.

Comment: This answer is severely underrated. Snippet Generator is a godsend.